# Generated regressors: using estimated value and residuals as regressors for another model when R2 is low

Tags: least-squares, residuals, r-squared

Consider three variables, $y, x, z$. Variable $y$ is a linear function of $x$ and $x$ has a 'part' that is driven by $z$ and another that is not. For example, the volume traded of a certain stock ($y$) is driven by last month's returns of this stock ($x$), which depends on a 'market' component (i.e., how well is the economy doing, the return of a market index, $z$) and other, idiosyncratic or unmodeled properties. To know that volume traded depends on last month's returns, it suffices to run a regression
$$
y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \varepsilon_i,
$$
but if one is interested in knowing how this effect is differentially carried by the market-driven variation and by idiosyncratic properties, one may first run regression
$$x_i = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 z_i + u_i,$$
and then *generate* the variables $\hat{x} = \hat{\alpha_0} + \hat{\alpha_1}z$ (the *market-driven* or explained part of returns) and $\hat{u}$ (the idiosyncratic, unexplained, or residual part of return).

These variables are then used to estimate
$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \hat{x}_i + \beta_2 \hat{u}_i + \varepsilon_i.$$

I'm assuming all needed conditional independences of error terms for this to be "OK".

**My question:** Does the consistency or unbiasedness of the parameters estimated in this last regression depend on the quality of the regression of $x$ on $z$? I.e., suppose the $R^2$ of the regression of $x$ on $z$ is really low ($z$ explains very little of $x$) or if the coefficient of $z$ in the regression of $x$ on $z$ is not significant, does this affect the interpretation of $\beta_1$ in the last model? (e.g., if not significant, could this be driven by the poor explanatory power of the regression that generated $\hat{x}$?).

I will be more than happy with a reference (book or article) instead of a full explanation.

Thanks!